# WPF text binding from variable changing in separate class/namespace

Tags: c#, wpf

I am struggling with Text binding in my WPF app.

1. Lets imagine that I have another working app (ex. windows service) with some data in it.
2. In my WPF app I would like to have folder "DATA" with class where data are introduced and in same folder another class which would include a void which will query my windows service
3. I would like to show this data in my WPF window.

To make it simpler - one class with data, one class with data changing and WPF window with showing this data.

Unfortunately I can not achieve this... When I am executing below code, my window is showing 0 instead 123.

I would like to achive that my window will show value 123.

1. file "Database.cs" in folder "Data" in project "example"

```
namespace example.Data
{
    public class Database
    {
        private int _testInt = 0;

        public int testInt
        { 
            get { return _testInt; } 
            set { _testInt = value; } 
        }
    }
}
```

2. file "Query.cs" in folder "Data" in project "example"

```
namespace example.Data
{
    public class Query
    {
        public Database _database;
        public void execute()
        {
           _database = new Database();
           _database.testInt = 123;
        }
    }
}
```

3. file "MainWindow.xaml.cs" in project "example"

```
namespace example
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public Data.Database _database;
        public Data.Query _query;

        public int testInt
        {
            get { return _database.testInt; }
            set { _database.testInt = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            _database = new Data.Database();
            _query = new Data.Query();

            _query.execute();
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

4. File MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding testInt}"
                       Foreground="White"
                       FontSize="15"
                       VerticalAlignment="Top"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       Margin="20,10,10,0" />
</Window>
```

P.S. If I will put

```
_database.testInt = 987;
```

to MainWindow.xaml.cs it is working properly - window is showing value 987 in textblock.

Comment: this appears to be basic WPF, not Xamarin

Comment: Try `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(testInt))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple instances of the `Database` object, a new one each time `Query.execute` is called and one in `MainWindow` constructor.

It's the data in the later that is displayed.

You should modify the content of this instance to see any change, for that, you must inject it in the `Query` object:

```
_query = new Data.Query(_database);

// ...

public class Query
{
    private readonly Database _database;

    public Query(Database database)
    {
        _database = database;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
       _database.testInt = 123;
    }
}
```

Finally you need a way to notify the view that the content as changed, that why `Database` should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

But at this point it's badly named, because it's a model in the MVVM pattern.

Comment: Thats IT. I don't know how i missed this. This is so obvious! Thank You!

P.S. Just for future users. There is small bug in Your answer: (It should be without "readonly" parameter
```
private Database _database;
public Query(Database database)
    {
        _database = database;
    }
```

Comment: It should be readonly, that means that the `DataBase` instance will stay unique, not that it's contant is immutable...

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly it didn't solve this... same situation stil..

Answer (score 0):

from the MVVM view, I think these answers from Orace and Jason are on a good way, both do not solve the problem completely.

1. Let the Mainwindow implement INotifyPropertyChanged
2. Let the query accept the new value:

   ```
    public void execute(int value)
    {
    //_database = new Database();
    // inject _database like in the answer above
    _database.testInt = value;
    }
   ```
3. When your `testInt` changes, let the `_query` deliver the change down to the "database" (btw: you do it vice versa) See code below:

   ```
       `public int testInt
             {get { return _database.testInt; } 
             `set { _query.execute(value); OnPropertyChanged(); }`
        }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            _database = new Data.Database();
            // the property change will change both the view and the model
            testInt = 987;
        }
   ```

Well, you have changed both model and view with one property change then, Good or not?!

Comment: It is also good point for this specific example. But as I mentioned - this void execute will not change just one int in the database, but will have a function to query windows service for multiple variables. At the end my ViewModel will check variables in the database and Model/class execute will constantly query another app (windows service) and constantly update variables in my app and UI.

Answer (score -1):

Just for future users. There is small bug in Orace's answer: (It should be without "readonly" parameter, because below You are writing to it.

```
private Database _database; 
public Query(Database database)
{
   _database = database;
}
```

Comment: readonly fields can be assigned in constructor